# Can't see the Distribution Provisioning in the list of Code Signing Identity

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, archive, provisioning-profile

I have a distribution  provisioning profile and I have successfully Archived the project but when I am trying to distribute the archive, the provisioning profile is not showing up in the list of Code Signing Identity! I have deleted the archive, restarted X Code, and created archive many times but still I am facing the same issue. I can't see the distribution provisioning in the list with which I have created the Archive but showing the development provisioning with same identifier. Please take a look on the image and please help!
Thanks-
[image]

Comment: down voters please explain before take the action of down vote.

Comment: @AhmadTK Did you get my question? If yes, please explain the person who are answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see your provisioning profile in that list you need to run a valid p12 certificate for that particular provisioning profile.

Try re-checking the p12 file of that provisioning profile and run it again.